# Set Locale when using Auth::loginUsingId for phpunit

Tags: laravel, testing, locale

I have several languages in my Laravel 5.2 app. Each locale is stored in DB in th User Model. So, each time a user log, the locale must update.

Thing is in my Test, I use a lot Auth::loginUsingId, because I need to test function with differents user profiles.

So, I don't want to append to each of those calls with a App::setLocale(Auth::user->locale), nor extract it to a function.

Any Idea how should I do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to address this problem is creating a middleware with

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($user = Auth::user()) {
        App::setLocale($user->locale);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

By handling all routes through this middleware, you can have the locale set automatically at each request.

Comment: yep, but I don't really need it to execute each request... I would like to use it just for my test